# Rewriterule with optional parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

this is my .htaccess file

```
..
RewriteRule ^songbook(?:/([a-z]))?/?$ music/songbook.php?char=$1 [L]
```

with that rule i can use the following url's:

```
http://www.example.com/songbook
http://www.example.com/songbook/

http://www.example.com/songbook/a
http://www.example.com/songbook/a/
```

So far so good. The problem occurs when i try the get the char in PHP, like so:

```
if (isset($_GET['char'])) {
   echo 'FOUND a char';

} else {
   echo 'there is NO char';
}
```

For some reason, it always finds a char, even when there is no char provided.
My rewrite rule says that the char is optional, but i guess i'm doing something wrong.

How do i write the rewriterule so that the char is optional so the if condition in PHP works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your rewrite rule always defines `char` in query string even if it's an empty string.
You have two options :

1- Edit your php:

```
if (isset($_GET['char'])  &&  !empty($_GET['char'])) {
   echo 'FOUND a char';
} else {
   echo 'there is NO char';
}
```

2- Edit your `.htaccess`:

Comment: im not sure which solution is best. I think i'll go with the php solution. thanks

Comment: It depends, but I'd go with @Croises's answer!  that's neater but add uppercase compatibility to your rule!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^songbook/?$ music/songbook.php [L]
RewriteRule ^songbook/([a-z])/?$ music/songbook.php?char=$1 [L]
```